# filling desired color while rotating the image in scipy

Tags: python, image, rotation, scipy

I am rotating an image using scipy as follows

```
    scipy.misc.imrotate(im,60)
```

The rotated image is filled with black values and i want white.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`scipy.misc.imrotate` just uses PIL behind the scenes.  You could simply do it using PIL, but it's suprisingly clunky.

It's better to just use `scipy.ndimage.rotate` instead.  (The functions in `scipy.misc` are somewhat obscure and rarely used.)

The `cval` kwarg controls the "background" value.

In your case:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage

data = 256 * np.random.random((10,10))
data = data.astype(np.uint8)

rotated = scipy.ndimage.rotate(data, 60, cval=255)
print rotated
```

Yields:

```
[[255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 255 255 150 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 255 160 234 179 152 255 255 255 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 255 120 206 114  19 173 188 255 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 172 113 144 159 162 175  89  43  62 255 255]
 [255 255 255  81 170 194 205 137 158 190 196 123 186 255]
 [255 255 115  67 118 101  53  33 108  34 125  61 255 255]
 [255 255 176 126 113 189 170 120 118  10 182 165 255 255]
 [255 150 209 101   9 146 213  99 134 162 133 255 255 255]
 [255 255 190 126 194 159 119  67 171 240 143 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 255 174 184 211  99 103 139 255 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 255 255 255 167 232  70 247 255 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 102 255 255 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255]]
```